# executing in current directory vs specifying executable linux

Tags: linux, path

I sure hope someone gets a great laugh at me...a lowly Windows boy.  I don't even know how to post the question (let alone google a solution). Here is the confusion:

I am using virtualbox with a trusty64 OS installed. I type:

$ cd /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin

$ ls

bundle  bundler  erb  erubis ...

$ bundler -v

: No such file or directory

$ /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundler -v

Bundler version 1.7.3

$

Honestly, I'm new to Linux which is probably now evident. But aren't these two equivalent? If I'm in a directory and execute "bundler -v" should I not get exactly the same result as I do when I explicitly type my current path and the executable together like: "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundler -v"?

Comment: The real reason for the error was that windows created the script file bundler during the provisioning of the vbox.  Script files that have Windows line endings \r\n don't run in Linux and cause the rather unedifying message, ":No such file or directory". The solution is to make the line endings in all linux scripts \n.  Very frustrating few hours lost on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a binary that the system knows about because it is in $PATH variable you can use the name of the program and any parameters, for example:

```
bundle -v
```

If your program is not in $PATH and you want to execute it in its current working directory, run:

```
cd /path/to/file/directory
./programname
```

or alternatively you could use absolute path, for example: `/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundler -v`

To find directories containing programs that the system knows about, run `echo $PATH` in your shell.

Take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164180/different-ways-of-executing-binaries-and-scripts

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and the link. For anyone following this, in the link, read the OPs own final summation of the way Linux handles paths and commands. It is quite complete. Wow is this different than windows...

Comment: I've been bothered during my short study of Linux by not having file extensions...but not enough to dig into it...big mistake. Finally, bang on my head with this post. I now get it and get why I've been so stuck so many times.

Comment: I have the bundle script in several directories. "which bundle" returns "/vagrant/bin/bundle". "/vagrant/bin" is the first object in my $PATH. However, I still get :No such file or directory when I run "bundle -v" AND when I type "/vagrant/bin/bundle -v".  The she-bang in the bundle
script in that directory is "#!/usr/bin/env ruby". So, although I understand more than I did before, I remain completely confused why my "bundle -v" won't run from that directory. The only script that runs is as stated in my OP "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/bundle -v".

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  132 Oct 28  2014 bundle

Comment: Ah, don't bother.  I found my problem.  My scripts have \r\n as line endings and that causes the problem.